# Solve a system of equations by expressing a RREF (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi I don't know how to do this problem, it is causing me quite a headache! any help would be appreciated.

Consider the augmented matrix:
\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 &-1 &3 &-5 &0\cr 4 &-4 &12 &-20 &0 \end{array}

Find the solution to the corresponding (homogeneous) system of equations by expressing A in RREF.

I need to put the system of equations in this format:

[(x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)] = r[()()()()] + s[()()()()] + t[()()()()]

I've solved for the RREF which is

\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 &-1 &0 &0 &0\cr 0 &0 &1 &-5/3 &0 \end{array}
I then tried to do back substitution of X2 = s and X4= t, but my answer was "linearly dependent."

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Could you explain, how did you get that RREF?

Comment: you're right, it should be r2 = r2-4r1 to clear it.

Comment: Yah. I think you can solve it now.